# Insert recipient id to message form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need assistance with creating code that will allow for a user to respond back to current message and automatically fill the recipient_id (from box) with the senders id.

So if I am reading a message from user 1. If I click `reply` the `from` box should have id 1 filled in as the recipient id.

So far I have only been able to fill in the recipient id based off the user id shown in the params.

new.html.erb:

```
<% render @message %>


<%= form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
    <p>
      To:<br />
      <%= f.text_field :recipient_id, :value => params[:user_id] %> 
    </p>

      <p>
        Subject:<br />
        <%= f.text_field :subject %>
      </p>
      <p>
        Message<br />
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </p>

      <%= submit_tag "Send"%>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @new_message = Message.new
    @message = Message.new
    @message.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
  end

 def reply
      @reply_message = Message.new
      @message = Message.new
      @message.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do:

```
<%= f.text_field :recipient_id, :value => @user.id %>
```

Comment: That would only reference the current user. I need for it to pickup the sender id from the current message. The sender id should always be used as the recipient_id when responding to a message.

Comment: I thought originally it would be @message.sender_id but that leaves the form blank.